# Import excel file to sql using bulkcopy

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have been able to import an excel file sql bulkcopy locally.  But when I publish the code to the server I get the following error messages:

Exception Message: 'C:\MyTest.xls' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Exception Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine

Here is code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="txtFile" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html> 


Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim excelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & txtFile.PostedFile.FileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""" 

    Using connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString) 
        'List columns you need from the Excel file   
        Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select [Name],[Location] FROM [Sheet1$]", connection) 
        connection.Open() 

        ' Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet   
        Using dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader() 
            ' SQL Server Connection String   
            Dim con As SqlConnection = GetConnection()

            Using bulkCopy As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(con) 
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblExcel" 

                'Define ColumnMappings: source(Excel) --destination(DB Table column)   
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name") 
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Location", "Location") 
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr) 
            End Using 

            CloseConnection(con)

        End Using 

    End Using 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first save the file (SaveAs(path), Use server.MapPath to map a relative dir) and then give the full path to the connection string.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail.  This is completly new to me trying to import an excel file.  Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ysf0192b.aspx You need to save the file to a pre-determined path and use that in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install the [Microsoft Office Access database engine](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en) on the server.